# React-native dependency error (com.atlassian.mobile.video okhttp-ws-compat)

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a React-native app and all of a sudden I started getting the following error:

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-config'.
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-config:_debugPublishCopy'.
>     Could not find com.atlassian.mobile.video:okhttp-ws-compat:3.7.0-atlassian1.
>            Required by:
>                cabm8:react-native-config:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.42.3-atlassian-1

I got rid of the module `react-native-config` but still facing a similar error:

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-maps'.
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-maps:_debugPublishCopy'.
>     Could not find com.atlassian.mobile.video:okhttp-ws-compat:3.7.0-atlassian1.
>            Required by:
>                cabm8:react-native-maps:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.42.3-atlassian-1

The issue seems to be related to `com.atlassian.mobile.video:okhttp-ws-compat:3.7.0-atlassian1` somehow.

I've tried reinstalling `node_modules`, removed the folders `android` and `ios` then restored them using git. What else could I try?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`com.atlassian.mobile.video` is not avaible on maven right now. To run your project you need to update it

Update your `react` and `react-native` version to in your `package.json` file

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.3",
"react-native": "0.43.1",
```

Then remove `node_modules` and do a `npm install` again

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks! I've just tried it and It did solve my original problem but encountering another issue now that might be due to outdated deps caused by react16.

Comment: Thanks @ishaan-sharma, to make it works using you suggestion I had to upgrade react to `16.0.0-alpha.6` (instead of `16.0.0-alpha.3` you suggested) as I had the error: `npm WARN react-native@0.43.1 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none was installed.`

Comment: you might need a `npm install --force` or else npm will throw and unmet peer dependency and skip the install on windows, happned to me quite a few times while trying to solve this problem

Comment: @Fuzaill'Corder correct, I forgot to mention it earlier as I was using linux

Comment: After this I also had to change the `protected` in `protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() { return BuildConfig.DEBUG; }` to `public` in MainApplication.java

Answer (score 23):

In your `build.gradle` (not in `android/app/build.gradle`) add this lines to force all dependency to `react-native` to specific version:

```
allprojects {

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.facebook.react' && details.requested.name == 'react-native') {
                    details.useVersion "0.39.0" // Your real React Native version here
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

This configuration worked for me. I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked for me after update Android Studio too.

Comment: This is a solution from the same issue thread that will get the version automatically: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14223#issuecomment-304509104

Answer (score 2):

FYI this error is tracked here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14225

I was able to fix by specifying the following versions of `react` and `react-native`:

- "react": "15.4.1",
- "react-native": "0.42.3"

See https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/480#issuecomment-304471394.

Comment: I think update react native version is not a good idea.  Because it may cause the other RN lib using in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your build.gradle(not in app/build.gradle) file in the android folder. you don't want to add react-native version manually.

```
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.facebook.react' && details.requested.name == 'react-native') {
                    def file = new File("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/package.json")
                    def version = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(file.text).version
                    details.useVersion version
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, looked in the source code but couldn't find a reference to "atlassian" anywhere so I turned off wifi (to see if any calls are being made to get an external resource) and got the following

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-google-analytics-bridge:_debugPublishCopy'.
>   Could not resolve com.atlassian.mobile.video:okhttp-ws-compat:3.7.0-atlassian1.
>              Required by:
>                  OneUps:react-native-google-analytics-bridge:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.42.3-atlassian-1
>   Could not resolve com.atlassian.mobile.video:okhttp-ws-compat:3.7.0-atlassian1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/atlassian/mobile/video/okhttp-ws-compat/3.7.0-atlassian1/okhttp-ws-compat-3.7.0-atlassian1.pom'.

If you follow that link it looks like that package has been removed which I guess is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

in your root build.Gradle force all dependencies to a specific version.

```
allprojects {
 configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy {
     eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
       if (details.requested.group == 'com.facebook.react' && details.requested.name == 'react-native') {
         details.useVersion "0.40.0" // Your React Native version here
       }
     }
   }
 }
  }
```